# Meaning of "for stem cell interventions"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> "The U.S. direct-to-consumer marketplace for stem cell interventions has been out of control, with hundreds of so-called clinics proliferating across the country," he said.[Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2018/05/09/fda-seeks-injunction-to-stop-two-stem-cell-companies-after-patients-blinded/?utm_term=.f71bac17b18c)

What does "for stem cell interventions" mean here?

I know the direct-to-consumer marketplace, but I am not sure what is "stem cell interventions" here.

When I looked for intervention, longman said:

> the act of becoming involved in an argument, fight, or other difficult situation in order to change what happens [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/intervention)

But still I do not get it, especially "for". What does it mean?

Comment: That would be a bit long to answer here, but you can look up "stem cell intervention" on the net and keep yourself occupied for a couple of hours... To get you started, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intervention_) has "Action taken to improve a medical disorder" as one of the meanings of "intervention".

Comment: @MrLister I googled, but there is no definition about stem cell intervention. Thanks. So it's a stem cell therapy. Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *medical* intervention is just another term for a procedure to help treat or cure a condition. As with the definition you found, it means interceding with the intent of modifying the outcome.

Stem cells are biological cells which are harvested for use in procedures. Medical procedures using stem cells may be referred to as "stem cell therapy", but clearly "intervention" is used too.

Because there are many different kinds of medical procedures, "stem cell intervention" would be considered the *name* of a medical procedure, or the name of a group of procedures which is why it can be referred to this way. Evidently these kinds of interventions are offered by various medical providers in the USA, and as medical care in this country is a competitive market with supply and demand it makes sense to describe it as "a marketplace", and there is a marketplace for stem cell interventions because there is a demand for them.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of ,, stem cell intervention'' is a simple stem cell treatment.
Actually, it is about treatment rather than an intervention. An intervention is more suitable for a surgical operation (surgical intervention).
According to the Oxford dictionary, it is correct to use the term **intervention**, but as we could see people are confused about seeing this term in this context. The stem cell treatment ( actually a stem cell**s** treatment -because there are millions of stem cells introduced into the body) is mostly done by an infusion of solution into the vein, spine, knee, etc. Before the treatment with stem cells, a surgical intervention is made(a liposuction) to harvest the fat tissue where fat stem cells reside.